# i want to pass parameter from one file to another via using JQUERY and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

am trying to pass a user parameter from  tag in 1st php file to other php file
My 1st file has the code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.activate').click(function() {

        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "activations.php",
           data: 'id='+ user_id,
           cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
                alert('user Updated');
                $("#row_"+user_id).hide();
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('request failed');
            }
        });
    return false;

    });
}); 
</script>

<button class='activate' id='".$row['id']."' name='active'>Activate</button></td>
```

when i click on the button, it shows the user id updated. that code is running fine. but the data is not going to other file. other file code is:

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;

?>
```

Comment: How do you know the id isn't making it to the other file?

Comment: in your success parameter, please add alert(response) and tell us what is alerted to you.

Comment: I guess $row['id'] should be inside php-tags, like <?php $row['id'];?> else tha value would literally be ".$row['id']."

Comment: Please open your browser's console and watch the request / response. It will reveal a lot to you about your AJAX including errors.

Comment: Yes. in alert i got the valid user_id on the script page but on other page i didn;t get any data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.activate').click(function() {

        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "activations.php",
           data: 
           {
              id: user_id
           },
           cache: false,
           success: function(response) {
                alert('user Updated');
                $("#row_"+user_id).hide();
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('request failed');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i got the success message that the user updated. but when i try to get the user_id as id on activations.php page. it gives an error. Undefined index.

Comment: check what the button id is from your web browser debugger. and before submitting ajax try to see the contents of user_id.